# ng-repeat parent child rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im stuck on this part for few days.

I have an array that has a object inside it, the object has a value of GenericID and IsSubsector, is there any possibility when the GenericID is 0 and IsSubSector is false it will be the parent row for the GenericID that has a value and IsSubSector true. I know it can be done in javascript. Is there other way I can do it alone in html with angularjs.

```
  <div class="container-fluid grid-padded">
                <table ng-table="roboticEditTable" class="table table-responsive table-condensed" style="width: 99.9% !important" show-filter="true">
                    <tbody ng-repeat="row in $data">
                        <tr id="row.Id" ng-click="changeSelection(row, $index)" ng-class=" { 'active': row.$selected } ">
                            <td title="RoboticEditTitle" class="text-center">
                                <div ng-show="editIndex!==$index">                        
                                    <button  ng-show="row.SectorDescription === 'None'" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $index }}" uib-tooltip-placement="top" ng-disabled="performingAction" uib-tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="<%= GlobalizationUtil.GetText(GlobalizationKey.Show) %>">
                                        <i class="fa fa-toggle-down"></i>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td title="labels.sector" filter="{'SectorCode': 'text'}" sortable="'SectorDescription'">{{ row.SectorCode + ' - ' }} {{ row.SectorDescription }} </td>
                            <td title="labels.glAccount" filter="{'AccountCode': 'text'}" sortable="'AccountCode'">{{ row.AccountCode + ' - ' }} {{ row.RGSCode + ' - ' }} {{ row.AccountDescription | ellipsis }}</td>
                            <td title="labels.articleCode">{{ row.ArticleCode }}</td>
                            <td title="labels.description">{{ row.Description }}</td>
                            <td title="labels.percentage">{{ row.VatPercent | percentage }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-parent="row.GenericID" >
                            <td class="col-sm-2"></td>
                            <td  class="col-sm-2" filter="{ 'row.SectorDescription': 'text' }" style="padding-left:35px;">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i> 
                                {{ row.SectorCode + ' - '}} {{ row.SectorDescription }}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ row.AccountCode + ' - ' }} {{ row.RGSCode  + ' - ' }} {{ row.AccountDescription | ellipsis }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.ArticleCode }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.Description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.VatPercent | percentage }}</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
```

im using data-parent as of now, but the id or index wont recognize it. The Parent id is the row.Id and the Children id is the GenericID

```
ID   another column     IsSubSector   GenericID
71   data.. data..          0            NULL
91   data.. data..          1             71
100  data.. data..          1             71
```

Comment: Can you show what `$data` looks like?

Comment: Hi i edited my question